# Android: how to detect dropdown closing in an AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, dropdownbox

I realized that if a dropdown is currently open in an AutocompleteTextView and you click outside the dropdown, the dropdown is dismissed, but the AutocompleteTextView is not losing the focus.

Can anyone think of a way to detect the dropdown closing?

Answer (score 8):

Use AutoCompleteTextView.onDismissListener (Added in API Level 17)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.OnDismissListener.html

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: I added your block of code to my onViewCreated() method, and added "implements AutoCompleteTextView.OnDismissListener" to my class definition.  My class extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment.  For some reason, I'm getting a compilation error on the implementation of OnDismissListener in the class definition--the error is that I haven't implemented "onDismiss() in OnDismissListener.  Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I worked it out, though I can't say I understand why.  I moved the onDismiss() method outside of the onViewCreated event, and left the autocomplete.setOnDismissListener(myclass.this) call in onViewCreated.  That got rid of the compilation error, and it actually worked.